# AngularJS NodeJS Cors Issues behind Firewall

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http-status-code-503

I have a AngularJS and NodeJS (API) application.
I had already enabled CORS on my NodeJS using CORS() nodejs library.

I included the required headers to enable CORS too.

I am having CORS issue only when I access the website from my company computer. It Works fine from my personal computers. Can anyone please guide me on what I am doing wrong. Any help or suggestion please.

Chrome Console Logs:

-------------------- Headers ---------------------

**General:**

```
Request URL:www.example.com:81/api/getdata
Request Method:GET
Status Code:503 Service Unavailable
Remote Address:111.111.11.111:81
```

**Response Headers:**

```
 Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
  Connection:close
  Content-Length:973
  Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
  P3P:CP="CAO PSA OUR"
  Pragma:no-cache
```

**Request Headers:**

```
  Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
  Connection:keep-alive
  Host:www.example.com:81
  Origin:http://www.example.com
  Referer:http://www.example.com/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

-------------------- Response: --------------------

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Web Page Blocked</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#e7e8e9">
 <div id="content">
 <h1>Web Page Blocked</h1>
 <p>Access to the web page you were trying to visit has been blocked in   accordance with company policy. Please contact your 

 system administrator if you believe this is in error.</p>
 <p><b>User:</b>  </p>
 <p><b>URL:</b> www.example.com:81/api/getdata </p>
 <p><b>Category:</b> unknown </p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Browser Console Error:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com:81/api/getdata. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

------ EDIT ----- 
Here is the cors() I am passing.

```
app.options('*',cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next){

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-type, Accept");

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

    next();

});
```

Comment: My guess would be that your company blocks port 81. Nothing to do with your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would try with another port.

Answer (score -1):

It's either a problem with your company firewall or a CORS problem.
Try to accept every origin in CORS module :

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
};

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next){
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for every origin.'});
});

app.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
});
```

Now you should receive response headers like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

If it still does not work, then port 81 must be blocked.

Another possibility is that the proxy of your company removes or blocks some headers which could explain why `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.example.com` is not present in your response headers

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would try your suggestions.

Comment: I did add cors() as given above but the header is being stripped by firewall. How do we solve the cors issue when your website is being accessed from a company  computers.